# Flask Tutorial: Could Not Import app in Visual Studio Code 1.37.1

Tags: python-3.x, flask, visual-studio-code

Am trying to learn Python3 / Flask using Visual Studio Code on my macOS machine.

Using:

- macOS Mojave (10.14.6)
- Visual Studio Code 1.37.1
- Python 3.7.4 64 bit (venv)

Tried the instructions in the following tutorial:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask

1. Created a virtual env by inside the newly created hello_flask folder:

```
   python3 -m venv venv
```

2. Opened the project folder in VS Code by running:

```
   code .
```

3. Opened the Command Palette (Shift-Cmd-P) and typed / selected:

```
Python:Select Interpreter
```

4. Picked Python 3.7.4 64-bit ('venv':venv)
5. Opened the Command Palette (Shift-Cmd-P) and typed / selected:

```
Terminal: Create New Integrated Terminal
```

6. Installed Flask via the VS Code Terminal using the following command:

```
pip3 install flask
```

7. Created a new file called app.py and entered in the following source code:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "Hello, Flask!"
```

8. When trying to run it inside VS Code's terminal:

```
(venv) user1@devbox:~/hello_flask$ python3 flask run
```

Output:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'flask': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
(venv) user1@devbox:~/hello_flask$
```

9. When trying this instead:

```
(venv) user1@devbox:~/hello_flask$ flask run
```

Output:

```
 * Serving Flask app "app.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: Could not import "app".
```

10. Even tried this:

```
export FLASK_APP=app.py
```

Output:

```
 * Serving Flask app "app.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: Could not import "app".
```

What am I possibly doing wrong?

Is there something wrong with the official documentation hosted by

Microsoft < https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask> ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main file name must be exported before running the `flask run`.

```
export FLASK_APP=app.py
```

Looks like your terminal is not in the same directory as `app.py`.

Flask did not find the `app.py` and raised error.

Docs:
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/quickstart/

Comment: Thanks for noticing that but when I changed it to FLASK_APP it still had the same error (just edited and fixed it inside the original post, as well).

Comment: could you have same output as you exported when running `FLASK_APP` in terminal?

Comment: Yes, its the same error output: "Error: Could not import "app".

Comment: I mean what is the output of `FLASK_APP` when you type in the vscode terminal?

Comment: could it be that app.py is inside hello_flask/.vscode/app.py and the Terminal is at hello_flask/(venv) ?

Comment: yes `app.py` should be in same directory as terminal.

Comment: Okay, by going inside .vscode, it worked - I might have to notify them to update their documentation. We kind of solved this together! Thanks @Debendra

Answer (score 7):

I updated my launch.json in vscode. My app.py resides in src folder. My terminal always pointed to Downloads/model_api/ and my app.py is in Downloads/model_api/src/app.py

```
 "FLASK_APP": "app.py"  --> "FLASK_APP": "src/app.py"
```

complete launch.json from vscode:

```
    "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python: Flask",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "module": "flask",
        "env": {
            "FLASK_APP": "src/app.py", # make update here
            "FLASK_ENV": "development",
            "FLASK_DEBUG": "0"
        },
        "args": [
            "run",
            "--no-debugger",
            "--no-reload"
        ],
        "jinja": true
```

Details about [launch.json in vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging)

Comment: VSCode can find this app.py. But now app.py cannot find other modules which are in the same folder as app.py. Getting error as:

 ` File "/Users/paritosh.sumrao/source/lms/app/application.py", line 6, in <module>
    from database import db
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'database' `

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Tokci (but didn't work for me)

**So here is what worked for me:**

in the launch.json file in .vscode directory, i've changed the value of the environment, named "FLASK_APP" from "app.py" to the actual name of my main file

> "FLASK_APP": "app.py"  --> "FLASK_APP": "foo.py"

make it look like this:

```
"configurations": [

    {
        "name": "Python: Flask",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "module": "flask",
        "env": {
            "FLASK_APP": "foo.py",
            "FLASK_ENV": "development",
            "FLASK_DEBUG": "0"
        },
        "args": [
            "run",
            "--no-debugger"
        ],
        "jinja": true
    }
]
```

}